# Convert a class object to Model in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I tried to create a Model object:

```
ClassA classA = getClassA();
Model model = new Model(classA);
```

When I tried to compile it, the following compile error occurs:

```
cannot find symbol : constructor Model(ClassA)
```

Why wouldn't ClassA be allowed here?

Comment: This was fixed by making ClassA Serializable :

      public class ClassA implements Serializable

Comment: Not a great idea to call your objects classA, since they're not instances of `java.lang.Class`

Comment: @Best: Yes, the constructor looks like this: `public Model(final T object)` and `T` is defined as `Model<T extends Serializable>`. Nevertheless you should use Generics whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a generic type to the model class.

Try this:

```
ClassA classA = getClassA();
Model<ClassA> model = new Model<ClassA>(classA);
```

Without the generic type, Java can't find an appropriate constructor, hence the error message.